# How could be make chat application and make changes in credentials via api

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a chat application in ios, how could be make this and make changes in credentials via API. is there any specific third party library for use and will able to make change through REST API without support of backend

Comment: can u specify exact issue.. ?  it includes what u tried and what u r facing the issues.

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR hello, i just want to add user via API in console and after that if i need , i can  update or reset my user credential via REST API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use FIREBASE it is  easy to use and easy to understand and you can also do whatever you want to do in your app according your requirements. It is easy to implement in application just to install a pod of firebase and create your app from firebase console . If you need any help you can ask.

firebase console :[click me for firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com)

Click on this `link` and click on `add project`

2.) And then follows the basic steps for set up your project.

3.) And download google.plist from console and drag it in your project.

install pods

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

Open your project

**appdelegate.m**

```
@import Firebase;//import 

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[FIRApp configure];// then configure firebase 
return YES;
}
```

> First you have to enable SIGN-IN-METHOD from firebase console.

**Go to firebase console**

1.) Click to you project

2.) Click "Authentication"

3.) Click "SIGN-IN-METHOD"

4.) Enable "Email/Password"

**Now open your project**

**Implement this method in your viewController.m**

```
#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>//import

-(void)firebaseSignUpReg
{
txtEmail.text=@"yourEmail@gmail.com";
txtPassword.text=@"12345678";

[[FIRAuth auth]
 createUserWithEmail:txtEmail.text
 password:txtPassword.text
 completion:^(FIRUser *_Nullable user,
              NSError *_Nullable error)
{
     if (error)
     {

         NSLog(@"error====%@",error.description);

         if (FIRAuthErrorDomain)
         {
             NSLog(@"error===%@",error);//print error


         }
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"%@ created", user.email);
         NSLog(@"%@ created", user);
         NSLog(@"%@ providerID", user.providerID);
         NSLog(@"%@ uid", user.uid);//uid



     }

 }];
 }
```

Comment: i just want to create user on firbase console via Rest API so i can update or reset it further?

Comment: You just create a app from console. Just click on new app and write bundle identifier of you app. It should be same.

Comment: Easiest and simplest way to use for chat is firebase. I will give you the url and you just follow that steps.

Comment: hii, i have already done this and made application but my requirment is want to create a user on firbase console in on calling Rest API

Comment: If you get any issue. You can share with me. I will try to resolve it. Thanks

Comment: hii @Dishant Rajput, it Really helped me. so can i update or reset these credential ?? ?                                                                                            thanks

Comment: yes you have to update it and try it in your code. Please upvote. Thanks :)

Comment: You can only upvote one answer.

Comment: Ok  i got it, cos this is my first chance to work here

Comment: no problem. I understand :) Thanks

Comment: i got one sample in swift, is there any sample for objective C for firbase cos i am facing some issues with swift variable like Lazy var..                                              thanks

Comment: In firebase console. It provide in both language you can check it from firebase set up. :)

Comment: hii, could you please help me to get channel like someone created in swift "  private lazy var channelRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("channels")".                                       otherwise how to create a group or list of person which i want to chat

Comment: Sure . I will provide you the source code of this in swift . It will take some time because i use firebase many times but in objective c. I will tell you when i get the code from my coding partners :)

Comment: hello, please give me any reference demo in objective c, because i already have one in swift, i am facing problem with variable types  you can send me on "manoj.shivhare@moptra.com"  thanks

Comment: ok. i wil provide you the code in objective c ... where you get problem please tell me. Then i will provide you the code of that part. Thanks :)

Comment: sure sir Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

The questions isn't very clear, but if you implement a chat application you could use a third party library like SendBird: https://sendbird.com
This will allow you to manage the conversations without your own backend.

Comment: @Reddy Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Even though you marked firebase as the solution, i would say its not the easiest and best solution. Sendbird is a lot easier to implement, i have implemented both and i found you get a lot of things for free like a chat interface, message handling is easier with Sendbird.

Comment: @Reddy , hii, if i use send bird, i'll be able to add user via Restful API and for further could i edit user credential?   Thanks

Comment: If you want to do more than just chat, then firebase is the better option.